# How to use AWS Personalize real time campaign invocations from AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, recommendation-engine

AWS Personalize is a new service by Amazon for personalized recommendations. Since this service is not yet integrated into boto3, how can I use it from Lambda function.
There is a way to invoke this from local using python with some additional steps mentioned here in step 3-6 [AWS Python SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/aws-personalize-set-up-aws-cli.html)

However this involves downloading some JSON's and adding models to AWS service.

Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should refer to [Getting started with aws-personalize in python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/getting-started-python.html?shortFooter=true) and [Creating a Campaign - Amazon Personalize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/campaigns.html?shortFooter=true) for getting how to use AWS personalize campaign. Also I think that you should add some more details to your question.

Comment: @NiraliAcharya I have referred the documentation and the process is simple, however BOTO 3 has not incorporated AWS Personalize service into their SDK and hence I am facing issues. The steps I mentioned (step 3-6 from link) in my post explains campaign invocation from local machine but I need to replicate same steps in Lambda environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working like this:

```
import boto3
import os
import json
import importlib

path = '/tmp/models/personalize-runtime/2018-05-22/'
os.makedirs(path)

BUCKET_NAME = 'personalize-dataset' # replace with your bucket name
KEY = 'personalize-runtime.json' # replace with your object key
FILENAME = '/tmp/models/personalize-runtime/2018-05-22/service-2.json'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, '/tmp/models/personalize-runtime/2018-05-22/service-2.json')


importlib.reload(boto3)
```

And you need to add an environmental variable to lambda: AWS_DATA_PATH == /tmp/models